# How make TTSplitViewController to work?

Tags: ipad, ios, three20

I try to implement a TTSplitViewController.

I already have the master & detail views.  However, after run the app, I only get a empty (both sides) TTSplitViewController. 
This is the code:

```
@interface MasterDetailViewController : TTSplitViewController { 
} 

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle 
*)nibBundleOrNil { 
        if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil 
bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) { 
                [self setupURLRouting]; 
        } 
        return self; 
} 

- (void)dealloc { 
        [super dealloc]; 
} 

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated { 
        [super viewWillAppear:animated]; 
        [self.leftNavigator openURLs:@"tt://help", nil]; 
        [self.rightNavigator openURLs:@"tt://menu/detail", nil]; 
}
```

I take a look at the TTCatalog and copy the code. However, after test it I see the behavior presented in TTCatalog is not what I want.

If before in the iPhone I have:

ListViewController 
DetailViewController

In iPad I will add

ListDetailViewController

And inside it, load at left ListViewController & show at right 
DetailViewController.

How do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you're still looking for a UISplitViewController solution with three20, try https://github.com/aporat/three20-splitview-example